# ggplot removing data without warnings

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Here's a data frame with dates and some random data.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(40100:40129, origin = "1899-12-30"), 
  rainfall = rnorm(30, 4)
)
```

When you plot the data the 30th value is not included on the graph. Once you execute the code notice that there is no bar above the date 2009-11-12. How do I get this 30th bar to appear on my plot? I *do* have to keep the limits as shown below, for reasons beyond the scope of this post. I'd also expect a warning in my console that data was removed from the plot, not sure why I don't get one.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(date, rainfall)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "white", color = "grey35") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + 
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "1 day",
    limits = c(min(dat$date), max(dat$date))
  ) +  
  NULL
```

Comment: it works when you use `max(dat$date)+1` as upper limit. Somehow, the last x is not shown, no idea why.

Comment: @Tjebo thanks for the tip but that adds an extra day `2009-11-14` to my x-axis, which screws up the scaling. Is there a way to remove the `2009-11-14` from the x-axis if I use your method above?

Comment: see below - answer

Comment: The first value (2009-10-14) is also hidden... This seems to be related to other problems people faced with `geom_bar` / `geom_col` & `scale_*_date` / `scale_*_datetime`, though I haven't seen this exact case before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience the safest way to specify axis limits is using `coord_cartesian` (and equals)

```
ggplot(dat, aes(date, rainfall)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "white", color = "grey35") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 day') +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(dat$date), max(dat$date)))
```

[image]